# How many user limit searches will github have?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to search the repository using github api, and I wonder how many people limit the number of people I can search.

For example, I'm trying to write an api as below, and I'm wondering how many people "user:XXX" is here.

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:taetaetae+user:black9p+user:asuraiv
```

I want you to help me with how many people are supported and if there are related documents.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the search api, you are limited by the maximum size of the search query which is [256 characters](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/search#limitations-on-query-length)
:

> The Search API does not support queries
> that:
>
> - are longer than 256 characters (not including operators or
>   qualifiers).
> - have more than five AND, OR, or NOT operators. These
>   search queries will return a "Validation failed" error message.

But if you want to reduce the number of request, you can use [GraphQL api](https://developer.github.com/v4/) and the following request using [aliases](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases):

```graphql
query { 
  user0: user(login: "taetaetae") {
    name
    login
    createdAt
  }
  user1: user(login:"black9p"){
    name
    login
    createdAt
  }
  user2: user(login:"asuraiv"){
    name
    login
    createdAt
  }
}
```

You could also use [fragments](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments) :

```graphql
query { 
  user0: user(login: "taetaetae") {
    ...UserFragment
  }
  user1: user(login:"black9p"){
    ...UserFragment
  }
  user2: user(login:"asuraiv"){
    ...UserFragment
  }
}
fragment UserFragment on User {
  name
  login
  createdAt
}
```

Output :

```json
{
  "data": {
    "user0": {
      "name": "taetaetae",
      "login": "taetaetae",
      "createdAt": "2015-02-12T02:27:40Z"
    },
    "user1": {
      "name": "Seongduck Paek",
      "login": "black9p",
      "createdAt": "2018-01-07T11:53:13Z"
    },
    "user2": {
      "name": "Ju Pyo Hong",
      "login": "asuraiv",
      "createdAt": "2017-08-04T16:23:09Z"
    }
  }
}
```

[Try this in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20user0%3A%20user%28login%3A%20%22taetaetae%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...UserFragment%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20user1%3A%20user%28login%3A%20%22black9p%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...UserFragment%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20user2%3A%20user%28login%3A%20%22asuraiv%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...UserFragment%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afragment%20UserFragment%20on%20User%20%7B%0A%20%20name%0A%20%20login%0A%20%20createdAt%0A%7D%0A)